# create an image of cloudlinux drive on VPS via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, images, dd, vps

we have a cloudlinux running on a VPS that we need to run some test's on. We do not have access to the VPS nor there is an option to clone this VPS.

Is there a way for us to use dd or some other tool to create an image via ssh? ie login into the cloudlinux as root and do a hot image to a remote location?

we have root access to the OS, but not to the vitalisation environment, so we cannot create a snapshot or use boot-able disk cloning tools. We have not tried anything yet.

We have root access to the OS and need to create a boot-able image/clone of the system. Not just copy file.

Comment: I've answered this before in [Copy (almost) entire filesystem with minimal effort](http://superuser.com/q/945980/83694).

Comment: First you say "We do not have access to the VPS" then you ask about an approach that involves logging in as root. Exactly what type of access do you or do you not have? What have you tried, and what were the results? Please [edit] your question to show us what you have tried already.

Comment: thank you for you answers. I've added additional information as requested.

Comment: I am not sure with control panel and virtualization technique your web host uses, however, If your web host allows you can try following approach.

1) Ask your web host to take backup of your VPS(complete VPS image.).
2) Create new VPS and restore it with the VPS backup.

Comment: creating a VPS image is not possible in this case