# Ubuntu 16.4 Filename Corruption after Backing up with dd

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-16.04, dd, ascii

I have downloaded the boot partition from a server I needed a local copy of using dd and SSH. 
I can boot up the partition using a virtual machine, however, I have noticed some file names are corrupted. It seems like the files were in use during the process. 
The filenames now look like ;68;48:70;10 (random example of the format) instead of letters. I have determined the numbers correspond to the ASCII codes of the file name. 
How can I fix the filenames so I can use the server copy for local development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never do a block device copy when any partition in it is mounted with write capability for the exact reason you discovered on your own: Files may be written as the copy is happening.

This is why there is the handy-dandy `rsync` command, which copies individual files from a mounted file system.  There is no risk of corrupting the file system because it maintains in control of the writes.  My answer in [Copy (almost) entire filesystem with minimal effort](https://superuser.com/a/946023/83694) can help you craft an appropriate `rsync` command to copy your file system.

If you don't know how to mount a partition without putting it into a virtual machine, you can create the disk image with `truncate -s 1G disk.img` (where `1G` is the size of the desired disk and `disk.img` is a file name of your choice) and then turn it into a block device by loopback [with `losetup`](https://superuser.com/a/684707/83694).  You can then partition the loopback device like a real disk, `mount` the partition you want, and then use `rsync` to copy the files from the server.

---

If you really want to do a block device copy, you can remount the source file system as read only (`mount -o remount,ro`) before starting the copy.  Obviously, there will be side effects if something on the source tries to modify a file it can no longer modify, and you cannot do this if the mount is busy.

If you cannot remount as read-only, you would have to reboot the source into a rescue environment where the source data would not be mounted, but this means downtime and a lot of hassle.